# MongoDB: Find documents which has exact array values and size

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Am trying to fetch documents which has exact elements in an array. I already knew the array size so am trying to use $all and $size operator it doesn't work out.

My Documents sample

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("6395b0d9d35a57df142862dd"),
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("63844feadf507942caaf90e3"),
        ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f")
    ],
    "type" : "SINGLE",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-12-11T15:58:41.625+05:30"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-12-11T15:58:41.625+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6395b0d9d35a57df142862ce"),
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("63844feadf507942caaf90e3"),
        ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f"),
        ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf34c0abc"),
    ],
    "type" : "SINGLE",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-12-11T15:58:41.625+05:30"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-12-11T15:58:41.625+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Above is the sample records which i have now i like to fetch the records which has exact users array size and if all the element matches to my array.

Am attaching my query below

```
db.conversations.find({ users: {$size: 2, $all: [ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f") ]}})
```

the query which i wrote above returns a document, which means my query is wrong i want to return if all the element matches with users array

Comment: I don't think I understand why the results you are getting are unexpected. The first document has a `users` field that is an array of size `2` and the (only) item from the `$all` list (ObjectId ending in `0f3f`) is indeed one of the two entries in `users` so that document matches. Are you saying that document shouldn't match because the other entry in the `users` array (`...90e3`) is not part of the `$all` list? Maybe [the `$allElementsTrue` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @user20042973 i want if all the elements are matching then return me the record, allElementstrue is aggregate operator can i get something like this in find query?

Comment: You can use `$expr` to bring in agg operators into the find() query. Alternatively, of course, you can just rewrite this in agg

Comment: but still its going in agg only right? anything in find query? i tried $eq but it will result based on the order, for me the order doesnt matter hence $eq doesnt workout

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
db.collection.find({
$and: [
 {
  users: {
    $size: 2
  }
},
{
  users: {
    $all: [
      ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f"),
      ObjectId("63844feadf507942caaf90e3")
    ]
  }
 }
]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/grPUTu9fivn)

Comment: It doesnt work if you read my tried query itself you can clearly see mentioning explicitly $and and my query both are same

Comment: From what you have described , your query seems to work as well , maybe good to add what is the expected  result exactly ?  , If you need only the matching record maybe check: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ohhgmHQ_ncq

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you clarified that this is the behavior that you are looking for:

"*i want if all the elements are matching then return me the record.*"

This means that your [current query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Po4cW3g5nhh) does not work as it returns this document:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6395b0d9d35a57df142862dd")
    "users": [
      ObjectId("63844feadf507942caaf90e3"),
      ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f")
    ],
    ...
  }
```

But that document contains an entry of `ObjectId("63844feadf507942caaf90e3")` in the `users` array which you don't want.

One solution here is to use [the `$allElementsTrue` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/). This component of the check would look something like this:

```
        "$allElementsTrue": [
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$users",
              "in": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this",
                  [
                    ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f")
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
```

What the approach above does is map over the `users` array to make sure that each entry is present in the array provided by the client. Here the list from the `$all` in the original question is placed as the second argument to `$in`.

An alternative approach, would be to use [the `$setDifference` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/). That might look as follows:

```
        $not: {
          $size: {
            "$setDifference": [
              "$users",
              [
                ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f")
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Here we are computing the logical difference between the array in the documents and the array passed into the query. We then check that output to see that the difference is empty (via the negation of the size).

> but still its going in agg only right? anything in find query?

What is the requirement for doing this outside of aggregation?

Regardless, these operators are not actually restricted for use solely within the aggregation framework. Via [the `$expr` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) we can use them inside of `find()` directly.

Therefore the full example for the first approach is as follows ([playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8-4t-Rui147)):

```
db.conversations.find({
  $expr: {
    "$allElementsTrue": [
      {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$users",
          "in": {
            "$in": [
              "$$this",
              [
                ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f")
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  users: {
    $size: 2
  }
})
```

And the second approach ([playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TkA6e_ZeCUa)):

```
db.conversations.find({
  $expr: {
    $not: {
      $size: {
        "$setDifference": [
          "$users",
          [
            ObjectId("638455e5fa983e9cf84c0f3f")
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  users: {
    $size: 2
  }
})
```